# Load a block on xlsx header

Tags: xlsx, tinybutstrong, opentbs

is there any way when using openTBS, to send blocks to an *.xlsx header? 
Like we do on word, load the block on header*.xml?

Thanks in advance,
regards

**UPDATE:**

yes, i found the header content in /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml, but still im trying to merge 2 blocks, base and header... im gonna post some code

```
$base = $this->_getBase();
$TBS->MergeBlock('base', $base);
if ( $this->have_header == 1) {
        if ($info['extension'] == 'docx') {
            $TBS->LoadTemplate('#word/header2.xml', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
        } elseif ($info['extension'] == 'xlsx') {
            $TBS->LoadTemplate('#xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml', OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8);
        } 
        $header =  $this->_getBase();
        $TBS->MergeBlock('header', $header);
    }
```

This is working for MS Word part, but on Excel this is giving me errors like

```
<br /><b>TinyButStrong Error</b> in field &#91;header.courseaction_ref...]: item 'courseaction_ref' is not an existing key in the array.
```

**UPDATE:**

this is what i have on my header..

```
[header;block=begin] Mapa de Presenças/Faltas
[header.course_code] - [header.course] - Acção nº [header.action_number] - Ref.ª: [header.courseaction_ref] [header;block=end]
```

Comment: Do you mean custom headers & footers? Those that you can edit in the dialog box "Page setup"? If it's so, those options are saved in the same XLS sub-file as the sheet contents.

Comment: yes, i think... the header which is repeated in all pages.. on Excel 2007 when you go to insert->header&footer.. what sub-file?

Comment: The header is included in the sheet. Nevertheless, it is only a text contents. So maybe doing a MergeBlock() is not accurate. can we have the snippet of the header part of your template ?

Comment: is that enough? im still having the same problem

Comment: well, i have this method working on other doc, but this one is still not working...

Comment: The error says that item `courseaction_ref` is not found in the data, i.e. `$header`. You can check this with a `var_export($header); exit;`. Anyway, in order to suppress the error message, you can replace `[header.courseaction_ref]` with `[header.courseaction_ref;noerr]`.

Comment: i fix this :) ill post soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i created a new method (_getHEADER) on PHP side, ofc..

```
private function _getHeader() {
    if (!isset($this->_queries['HEADER'])) {
        return array();
    }
    return $this->_getOne('HEADER');
}
```

and when the documente have header ill do this

```
$header =  $this->_getHeader();
        $TBS->MergeBlock('header', $header);
```

and of course, i have 2 sql blocks, base and header :)

well im not sure if this is the best way, but its working :)